# Fill many small gaps in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path, fill

I traced a bitmap and after some tweaks I have what you can see in the image below (it's a detail of the whole canvas). As you can see some small gaps exist in the middle of the PCB traces. All the image is a single path.

Is there a way I can fill/delete all these small gaps automatically, while not affecting the middle of those big circles?

A sample in SVG format can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/goncalor/8129ab7efdc64bb963126494b21de1cc).

[image]

Comment: Please provide SVG file or some context: Are the traces and the holes a single path or 2 overlapping paths?

Comment: @Juancho I edited my question and now provide a SVG file. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to use the node editor (F2), select the nodes which are delimiting these *gaps* and deleting them?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini Yes, deleting the delimiting nodes instead of filling does indeed work. Yet, a somewhat automated way to delete them is desirable, because there are so many of them.

Comment: There are not so many nodes... but you can also increase border size and convert the border to path. Or follow @Juancho answer, which is perhaps the fastest way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your file contains a sigle path, where the tiny holes and spurious white scratches are path borders just like all others.

If you select your huge path and call *Path -> Break Apart*, you will end up with many simpler closed paths, where the holes and scratches will also appear as paths.

At this point, if you call *Path -> Combine* you will get back to the beginning, where one path inside another will appear as a hole. Don't to this.

Instead, with all the subpaths still selected, call *Path -> Union*. Voilá!

All overlapping holes and scratches will be merged with the bigger traces.

So the recipe is *Break Apart* and then *Union*.

Good luck cloning that PCB.

Comment: Your solution closes the scratches. But unfortunately it also closes the holes, which I wish to keep in this case. This time I'm not cloning a PCB, btw. This is to use as part of some promotional material. If it was for cloning, losing the holes would be perfectly fine :)

Comment: You can add by hand the holes, using circles and performing a *difference*.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini Yeah, that would work. Selecting the holes is much easier than selecting the scratches, so I think this is a good enough option. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A rough way to elliminate only the scratches but not the holes is to superimpose 2 slightly offset versions of the whole path:

Select the path, duplicate it (<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>), offset the duplicate a couple of pixels down (or down and to the right if you have vertical scratches). Offseting the duplicate can be done with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + arrows.

Now select both the original and the duplicate, and do *Path -> Union*.

Your holes will shrink a bit, your traces will grow a couple of pixels, and maybe some part of a scratch remains, but most should be gone.